# Sorting a Flex Array

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, sorting

I have created an array as shown below

```
protected function getMyArray(dataArray:Array):Array
    {
        var labelList:Array=new Array;
        for each (var property:Object in dataArray)
        {
            if (labelList[property.bucketTime] != property.bucketTime)
                labelList[property.bucketTime]=property.bucketTime;
        }
        return labelList;
    }
```

Is it possible to sort the array labelList based on property.bucketTime?

Edit: Sample input dataArray will be like this :

```
var tempObj:Object = new Object;
            tempObj.bucketTime = DateField.stringToDate("30-01-2010", "DD-MM-YYYY").time;
            tempObj.score = 76;
            dataArray.addItem(tempObj);

            tempObj = new Object;
            tempObj.bucketTime = DateField.stringToDate("13-02-2010", "DD-MM-YYYY").time;
            tempObj.score = 21;
            dataArray.addItem(tempObj);

            tempObj = new Object;
            tempObj.bucketTime = DateField.stringToDate("30-03-2010", "DD-MM-YYYY").time;
            tempObj.score = 10;
            tempArry.addItem(tempObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I sorted the labelList Array.Please find my solution below. Let me know if there is any better way to achieve this.

```
var termObject:Object = ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(labelList);
        var termsArray:Array = termObject.properties;
        var sortedColumnArray:Array = new Array;
        for each(var term:Object in termsArray){
            if(labelList.hasOwnProperty(term)){
                sortedColumnArray.push(labelList[term]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless `bucketTime` is a number; then you aren't actually populating the array.  You're just adding properties to the Array Object, almost like it were a [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html).  I've seen a Dictionary called Associative Array's and Structures in other languages.

If that is the case, an you're using the Array class as a dictionary, then there is no way to sort it.  The very nature of such a structure is that they are not sortable.

However, if `property.bucketTime` is a number, and you are trying adding items to the array as if they were an array, you can sort using the [Array.sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort%28%29) or [Array.sortOn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) methods.

Comment: property.bucketTime is a number.I tried labelList.sort(Array.DESCENDING), but the Array is not getting sorted.

Comment: @kbgn27 Either give us sample data and tell us what results your seeing and what results you were expecting or give us a full runnable sample to demonstrate your problem so we can test ourselves.  ( Or do both)

Comment: @kbgn27 Really?  labelList.sortOn("bucketTime") doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Flextras.com : I have added a sample dataArray.Hope this helps. @Brian Genisio : I tried sortOn  and it doesn't work.